# Allow concurrent executions of two methods but not both at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, locks

I have two instance methods `method1` and `method2` of an singleton object. `method1` can be run concurrently by separate threads. Meaning we can have 5 threads each running `method1` at the same time or 1 thread running `method2` at the same time.

I want to prevent `method1` from running when `method2` is running and `method2` from running when `method1` is running.

I thought about synchronizing both methods like the code below, this solves the issue where both methods can't be executed at the same time, but it will also prevent my 5 threads from running `method1` simultaneously, even if `method2` is not running.

```java
void synchronized method1() {
     //do something
}

void synchronized method2() {
    //do other thing
}
```

First time using java multi-threading so appreciate some advice, thanks.

**EDIT**: seems like `readWriteLock` is the way to go

Comment: So you want to have 2 states -- your class will either be running method 1 or running method 2.  When/how do you want to switch between them?

Comment: @MattTimmermans `method2` is a cache refresh, triggered by a cron job. I want all calls to the api `method1` to await until the cache refresh is complete

Comment: Do you really need multiple cache refreshes running at the same time?

Comment: Actually no, the cache refresh will happen once an hour. Updated

Comment: This is a classic readWriteLock situation.

Comment: Deleted my "answer," and re-opened. @JimGarrison is correct. If only one thread\* (the cache refresher) ever wants to run your `method2` then a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) probably is just the thing. The cache refresher (`method2`) would be the "writer," and all of the other threads would be the "readers." \[\*My eyes skipped over the part where you said that just one thread calls `method2`. Sorry.]

Comment: @SolomonSlow Not sure why you reopened, this is a duplicate

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Indeed a read write lock is what I needed.

Comment: @JimGarrison, Didn't really want to re-open it per se. I wanted to retract my vote is all. I wasn't thinking of it as a duplicate when I voted to close in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to use `ReadWriteLock` in this case.
As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) says:

> The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads,
> so long as there are no writers. While the write lock is exclusive.

The code may look like the following:

```
  ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

  void method1() {
    final var readLock = lock.readLock();
    try {
      readLock.lock();
      //do something
    }
    finally {
      readLock.unlock();
    }
  }

  void method2() {
    final var writeLock = lock.writeLock();
    try {
      writeLock.lock();
      //do other thing
    }
    finally {
      writeLock.unlock();
    }
  }
```